# How to copy a field in CRM 2016 (to another entity)

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In CRM 2016 On premise I have a field on an entity that I want to copy to another entity.
This field has a lot of functionality attached to it, and I do not wish to have to make it again (and again and again).

I have attempted with the XrmToolBox and its Attribute Editor, as was advised from Google, but this does not have this option. Also the answers from Google are several years old.

I realize that there might be some issues of copying a field since it may have a lookup or other kinds of references that my copy (or the other entity) does not have access to for one reason or another.

But still, if anyone knows how to do this, or anything in that direction it would be a great help.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with a lot of functionality, can you expand what that field does make exactly?

Comment: Manual field creation is recommended.. we dont have any tool yet.. else we can modifiey customization zip file but i wont support fully.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Attribute Editor, the Data Import Wizard allows you to create new fields.

I am unaware of any tool that will replicate a field's participation in forms, form events, views, plugins, processes, business rules, reports, etc. so those will require either manual configuration or custom programming (and the custom programming route may be cost prohibitive unless you are doing this for many entities on an ongoing basis).

For the sake of completeness I'll mention that an **unsupported** possibility would be to "hack" a solution file containing the field. While this would hypothetically allow you to do some of what you're looking to do (like change the entity), I would avoid it.